# Creating a Document object

Tags: java, design-patterns, dom

These are the steps for creating a Document object:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why do we need a DocumentBuilderFactory? Isn't it enough to have a DocumentBuilder to create Documents? (supposing a few constructors are not enough)
2. [newDocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newDocumentBuilder%28%29) is an abstract method. How is it called?
3. What are the design patterns used here and what is their role?

Answer (score 1):

`DocumentBuilderFactory` is an abstract class. That doesn't mean you can't call static methods belonging to that class.

Have a look here at what *DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()* really does.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()

> Obtain a new instance of a DocumentBuilderFactory. This static method creates a new factory instance. This method uses the following ordered lookup procedure to determine the DocumentBuilderFactory implementation class to load:
>
> 1. Use the javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory system property.
> 2. Use the properties file "lib/jaxp.properties" in the JRE directory. This configuration file is in standard java.util.Properties format and contains the fully qualified name of the implementation class with the key being the system property defined above. The jaxp.properties file is read only once by the JAXP implementation and it's values are then cached for future use. If the file does not exist when the first attempt is made to read from it, no further attempts are made to check for its existence. It is not possible to change the value of any property in jaxp.properties after it has been read for the first time.
> 3. Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory in jars available to the runtime.
> 4. Platform default DocumentBuilderFactory instance.
>
> Once an application has obtained a reference to a DocumentBuilderFactory it can use the factory to configure and obtain parser instances.

Now that you know how the factory tries to load the correct class. The instance returned by *newInstance()* will be an implementation of *DocumentBuilderFactory*. This implementation implements the abstract method * newDocumentBuilder* which will create the document builder for that given implementation.

It's obvious the factory pattern is used here.

Comment: Thanks! But what is the role of DocumentBuilder? Why are there 2 classes needed in order to construct a Document object?

Comment: The document builder hides the implementation and construction details of the document.